# Assign multiple repeated vectors as values in another column

Tags: r

I have a dataset with many NAs but I can fill these NAs with alternative names. The purpose is to use these names for something after, like a merge of the dataset by matching values.

However, I cannot assign these character vectors because its not the size of the dataframe.

For example:

```
join_pop1[is.na(join_pop1$UK_Districts.y)] <- pop_names
```

> x Input has size 19 but subscript `is.na(join_pop1$UK_Districts.y)` has size 1437.

Essentially I want each name to be assigned to those values with NAs for each unique city, for example this is what a glimpse of my dataset looks like:

```
# A tibble: 132 x 2
   UK_Districts.x                        UK_Districts.y
   <chr>                                 <chr>         
 1 Abertawe - Swansea                    NA            
 2 Abertawe - Swansea                    NA            
 3 Abertawe - Swansea                    NA            
 4 Abertawe - Swansea                    NA            
 5 Brent London Boro                     NA            
 6 Brent London Boro                     NA            
 7 Brent London Boro                     NA            
 8 Brent London Boro                     NA            
 9 Bro Morgannwg - the Vale of Glamorgan NA            
10 Bro Morgannwg - the Vale of Glamorgan NA
```

Expected outcome:

```
# A tibble: 132 x 2
   UK_Districts.x                        UK_Districts.y
   <chr>                                 <chr>         
 1 Abertawe - Swansea                    Swansea            
 2 Abertawe - Swansea                    Swansea       
 3 Abertawe - Swansea                    Swansea       
 4 Abertawe - Swansea                    Swansea       
 5 Brent London Boro                     Brent            
 6 Brent London Boro                     Brent            
 7 Brent London Boro                     Brent            
 8 Brent London Boro                     Brent            
 9 Bro Morgannwg - the Vale of Glamorgan Vale of Glamorgan            
10 Bro Morgannwg - the Vale of Glamorgan Vale of Glamorgan
```

Reproducible code:

```
#city names to assign
pop_names <- c("Swansea", "Brent", "Vale of Glamorgan", "South Bucks", "Cardiff", 
"Caerphilly", "Newport", "Neath Port Talbot", "City of London", 
"Bristol, City of", "Derby", "Leicester", "Peterborough", "Plymouth", 
"Portsmouth", "Southampton", "Stoke-on-Trent", "Westminster", 
"Wolverhampton", "Herefordshire, County of", "Shepway", "Merthyr Tydfil", 
"Bridgend", "Pembrokeshire", "Ceredigion", "Denbighshire", "Monmouthshire", 
"Carmarthenshire", "Flintshire", "Isle of Anglesey", "Somerset", 
"Brighton and Hove", "Wrexham")

join_pop1 <- structure(list(UK_Districts.x = c("Abertawe - Swansea", "Abertawe - Swansea", 
"Abertawe - Swansea", "Abertawe - Swansea", "Brent London Boro", 
"Brent London Boro", "Brent London Boro", "Brent London Boro", 
"Bro Morgannwg - the Vale of Glamorgan", "Bro Morgannwg - the Vale of Glamorgan", 
"Bro Morgannwg - the Vale of Glamorgan", "Bro Morgannwg - the Vale of Glamorgan", 
"Buckinghamshire", "Buckinghamshire", "Buckinghamshire", "Buckinghamshire", 
"Caerdydd - Cardiff", "Caerdydd - Cardiff", "Caerdydd - Cardiff", 
"Caerdydd - Cardiff", "Caerffili - Caerphilly", "Caerffili - Caerphilly", 
"Caerffili - Caerphilly", "Caerffili - Caerphilly", "Casnewydd - Newport", 
"Casnewydd - Newport", "Casnewydd - Newport", "Casnewydd - Newport", 
"Castell-nedd Port Talbot - Neath Port Talbot", "Castell-nedd Port Talbot - Neath Port Talbot", 
"Castell-nedd Port Talbot - Neath Port Talbot", "Castell-nedd Port Talbot - Neath Port Talbot", 
"City and County of the City of London", "City and County of the City of London", 
"City and County of the City of London", "City and County of the City of London", 
"City of Bristol ", "City of Bristol ", "City of Bristol ", "City of Bristol ", 
"City of Derby ", "City of Derby ", "City of Derby ", "City of Derby ", 
"City of Leicester ", "City of Leicester ", "City of Leicester ", 
"City of Leicester ", "City of Peterborough ", "City of Peterborough ", 
"City of Peterborough ", "City of Peterborough ", "City of Plymouth ", 
"City of Plymouth ", "City of Plymouth ", "City of Plymouth ", 
"City of Portsmouth ", "City of Portsmouth ", "City of Portsmouth ", 
"City of Portsmouth ", "City of Southampton ", "City of Southampton ", 
"City of Southampton ", "City of Southampton ", "City of Stoke-on-Trent ", 
"City of Stoke-on-Trent ", "City of Stoke-on-Trent ", "City of Stoke-on-Trent ", 
"City of Westminster London Boro", "City of Westminster London Boro", 
"City of Westminster London Boro", "City of Westminster London Boro", 
"City of Wolverhampton  ", "City of Wolverhampton  ", "City of Wolverhampton  ", 
"City of Wolverhampton  ", "County of Herefordshire", "County of Herefordshire", 
"County of Herefordshire", "County of Herefordshire", "Folkestone and Hythe", 
"Folkestone and Hythe", "Folkestone and Hythe", "Folkestone and Hythe", 
"Merthyr Tudful - Merthyr Tydfil", "Merthyr Tudful - Merthyr Tydfil", 
"Merthyr Tudful - Merthyr Tydfil", "Merthyr Tudful - Merthyr Tydfil", 
"Pen-y-bont ar Ogwr - Bridgend", "Pen-y-bont ar Ogwr - Bridgend", 
"Pen-y-bont ar Ogwr - Bridgend", "Pen-y-bont ar Ogwr - Bridgend", 
"Sir Benfro - Pembrokeshire", "Sir Benfro - Pembrokeshire", "Sir Benfro - Pembrokeshire", 
"Sir Benfro - Pembrokeshire", "Sir Ceredigion - Ceredigion", 
"Sir Ceredigion - Ceredigion", "Sir Ceredigion - Ceredigion", 
"Sir Ceredigion - Ceredigion", "Sir Ddinbych - Denbighshire", 
"Sir Ddinbych - Denbighshire", "Sir Ddinbych - Denbighshire", 
"Sir Ddinbych - Denbighshire", "Sir Fynwy - Monmouthshire", "Sir Fynwy - Monmouthshire", 
"Sir Fynwy - Monmouthshire", "Sir Fynwy - Monmouthshire", "Sir Gaerfyrddin - Carmarthenshire", 
"Sir Gaerfyrddin - Carmarthenshire", "Sir Gaerfyrddin - Carmarthenshire", 
"Sir Gaerfyrddin - Carmarthenshire", "Sir y Fflint - Flintshire", 
"Sir y Fflint - Flintshire", "Sir y Fflint - Flintshire", "Sir y Fflint - Flintshire", 
"Sir Ynys Mon - Isle of Anglesey", "Sir Ynys Mon - Isle of Anglesey", 
"Sir Ynys Mon - Isle of Anglesey", "Sir Ynys Mon - Isle of Anglesey", 
"Somerset West and Taunton", "Somerset West and Taunton", "Somerset West and Taunton", 
"Somerset West and Taunton", "The City of Brighton and Hove ", 
"The City of Brighton and Hove ", "The City of Brighton and Hove ", 
"The City of Brighton and Hove ", "Wrecsam - Wrexham", "Wrecsam - Wrexham", 
"Wrecsam - Wrexham", "Wrecsam - Wrexham"), UK_Districts.y = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -132L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `str_extract` from `stringr` package.
First we create a pattern of `pop_names`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
pattern <- paste(as.character(pop_names), collapse = "|")

join_pop1 %>% 
    mutate(UK_Districts.y = str_extract(UK_Districts.x, pattern))
```

output:

```
 UK_Districts.x                        UK_Districts.y   
   <chr>                                 <chr>            
 1 Abertawe - Swansea                    Swansea          
 2 Abertawe - Swansea                    Swansea          
 3 Abertawe - Swansea                    Swansea          
 4 Abertawe - Swansea                    Swansea          
 5 Brent London Boro                     Brent            
 6 Brent London Boro                     Brent            
 7 Brent London Boro                     Brent            
 8 Brent London Boro                     Brent            
 9 Bro Morgannwg - the Vale of Glamorgan Vale of Glamorgan
10 Bro Morgannwg - the Vale of Glamorgan Vale of Glamorgan
# ... with 122 more rows
```

Comment: I like this approach! Will keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, we may use `regmatches/regexpr` after constructing the `pattern`

```
pattern <- paste(pop_names, collapse = "|")
join_pop1$UK_Districts.y <- regmatches(join_pop1$UK_Districts.x, 
    regexpr(pattern, join_pop1$UK_Districts.x))
```